# Handling loops with promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm new to handling promises and I need to loop on their result value until I get the one I needed :

```
let index = 0;
while(!flag) // loop until result inside the promise is equal to "something"
{
    funcReturningPromise(index).then((result)=>{
        if(result === "something"){
            doSomething(result);
            flag = 1; // How can I send this result back to my function so I can stop looping ?
        }
        index++;
    });
}
```

How can I get a "callback" so that I can stop looping once I have the promise I wanted ? (I know that)

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can't. not with a regular loop anyway. your loop is not going to wait for whatever asynchronous operations your promise is doing. it's quite opssible the entire loop is finished before the first promise is even returned... also, it's really important to format your code properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have ECMAScript 2017 available, you can achieve this with [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
async function waitForFlag() {
    let index = 0;
    while(!flag) // loop until result inside the promise is equal to "something"
    {
        const result = await funcReturningPromise(index);
        if(result === "something"){
            doSomething(result);
            flag = 1;
        }
        index++;
    }
}
```

(Obviously you then could also use `break` to exit the loop)

Comment: Although in this particular case that's a very silly way to loop - you could just `let i; for(i = 0; await funcReturningPromise(i) !== "something"; i++); doSomething("something");` :D

Answer (score 1):

Like @Occam'sRazor mentioned in comment, it is not quite possible, atleast using regular loops anyways.

```
const getSomething = (index, callback) => 
  funcReturningPromise(index)
    .then(result => 
      result === 'something' ? callback(index) : getSomething(index++, callback)
    .catch(() => getSomething(index++, callback))

getSomething(0, doSomething)
```

HTH, written from top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Although it seems like a horrible thing to do, as your application might end up in an infinite loop, you can still achieve this using a recursive function

```
function myfunc() {
   checkTillSuccess(0);
}

function checkTillSuccess(flag) {
   if(!flag) {
      funcReturningPromise(index).then((result)=>{
        if(result === "something"){
            doSomething(result);
            checkTillSuccess(1)
        }
      }).catch(() => {
          checkTillSuccess(0)
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: this is incomplete - the `checkTillSuccess()` function is asynchronous, yet doesn't itself return a `Promise` so that the calling function can synchronize with it.

Comment: Ah, I see you have `doSomething(result)` hard coded in that function.  That's one way of doing it, but it's poor "separation of concerns".

Comment: @Alnitak, I am aware its hardcoded, the main concern of OP was something else, so I emphasised my answer on that.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in the comments, you can't do that with a regular loop because a regular loop is synchronous and promises are not. You could use recursion to do some async "looping" though.

```js
let index = 0;
(function recurse(callback) {
  funcReturningPromise(index).then((result) => {
    index++;
    console.log("did something with index "+index);
    if (index === 3){
        // stop looping
        callback();
    }else{
        // keep looking
        recurse(callback);
    }
  });
})(function(){
    // The looping has completed
    console.log("done looping");
});

function funcReturningPromise() {
  return new Promise(d => setTimeout(d, 1000));
}
```